# How to set Rviz to 60 Hz?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to set Rviz to 60 Hz according to David Gossow´s post here:
http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/Oculus-Rift-Integration-in-RViz-td4020193.html

How can I do so?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223528/how-to-set-rviz-to-60-hz?/) by [kubiak54](https://answers.ros.org/users/25482/kubiak54/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2016-01-05

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using a newer version of ROS such as Indigo or Jade, the ability to set the frame rate is built into rviz.

In the "Displays" panel (usually on the left side of the window), within "Global Options", there should be a option for "Frame Rate", which defaults to 30. Change this value to 60.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kubiak54](https://answers.ros.org/users/25482/kubiak54/) on 2016-01-05**:
Doh I was totally blind haha, thanks.